# Add closest facility as an attribute to a point in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst

Is there a way, after performing a closest facility analysis, to add/save the closest facility number/name/unique ID to the incident?

I plan to then use this attribute to create a route going from one incident to another incident via this closest facility, which means I have to somehow save it / keep track of which facility is closest for all incidents.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @ChrisW](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108868/add-closest-facility-as-an-attribute-to-a-point-in-arcmap/211711#comment155279_108868):

> The results of the solver have to be exported to be saved/manipulated.
>   The attributes table of those results should have the relationship
>   you're looking for (it may be coded as FIDs or OIDs, but it should be
>   there), and then it would just be a join/export bit of manipulation to
>   get the final result you want.